# About Web_Reference_Folder

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I see Web_Reference_Folder being used in Sharepoint code examples but have no idea what it is.

What is Web_Reference_Folder?
and
How do I access it or consume it?

Code Example from (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkoutfile(v=office.12).aspx):

```
Web_Reference_Folder.Lists listService = new Web_Reference_Folder.Lists();
listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
string fileCheckout = "http://Server_Name/sites/Subsite/Shared Documents/MyFile.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [msdn blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/trobbins/archive/2004/08/25/220551.aspx) , maybe it helps.

Some context about Web_Reference_Folder from the post:

> Web_Reference_Folder_Name represents the folder name used for the
>   reference to the Web service in Visual Studio .NET, and Service_Name
>   represents the name of the class providing methods that can be called
>   through the Web service.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use SharePoint web services in your code, you have to add web reference of the service in your project. Generally it is done by right click > Add web reference and then provide `http:///_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl`. That will generate a new web reference folder having appropriate classes that you can use to call the service.

Now say for example you used name `localhost` while adding web reference, it will add localhost folder in your project under web reference.

So, in that case your code should be `localhost.Lists listService = new localhost.Lists();`